# Writing data in file using FIlewriter

Tags: java, io, filewriter

I am making a simple program that put data into a file using `FileWriter`.

But I am facing a problem. My code is creating the fie but not putting data into the file.

```
import java.io.*;

class Temp
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
        FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("ma.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
        String str="dslkm dsk";
        bw.write(str);
    }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

You need to flush and close the writer.

```
bw.flush();
bw.close();
```

Even just closing the writer should be enough, since it automatically flushes before closing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be:

```
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
        FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("ma.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
        String str="dslkm dsk";
        bw.write(str);
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
    }
```

Comment: oh, I have seen two responses just now. I am little bit late without refreshing  the question.

Answer (score 0):

A file writer always need to be closed or flushed. Otherwise there is no guarantee to the write the `bytes`/`characters` in it to be written in your file.And it's better to use `fileWriter`  with `try-catch-finally` block -

```
try {
       FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("ma.txt");
       BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
       String str="dslkm dsk";
       bw.write(str);

    } catch (IOException ex){
       System.err.println("Couldn't log this: "+s);
    }finally{
       bw.close();
    }
```